# Pandas split the columns to mutiple rows

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multiple-columns

I'm new to Python **Pandas**.

I currently have an excel data, part of them is like below.AS you can see, each row may have many Suppliers and Supplier PNs. What I need is to keep the P/N and Description column, and split the other columns to rows.

```
 Supplier PN Supplier.1      Supplier PN.1          Supplier.2  \
0  GRM1555C1H101JA01D      YAGEO  CC0402JRNPO9BN101  GRM1555C1H101JA01J   
1      04025A6R8CAT2A      KEMET   C0402C689C5GACTU                 NaN   
2      04025A3R9CAT2A        NaN                NaN                 NaN   

                      Supplier PN.2  
0  Murata Electronics North America  
1                               NaN  
2                               NaN
```

[image: data]

**What I Expect is:**

[image: ![enter image description here]]

```
        P/N                     Description            Supplier  \
0  302-462-326      CAP CER 0402 100pF 5% 50V              MURATA   
1  302-462-326      CAP CER 0402 100pF 5% 50V               YAGEO   
2  302-462-326      CAP CER 0402 100pF 5% 50V  GRM1555C1H101JA01J   
3  302-462-012  CAP CER 0402 6.8pF 0.25pF 50V     AVX Corporation   
4  302-462-012  CAP CER 0402 6.8pF 0.25pF 50V               KEMET   
5  302-462-009  CAP CER 0402 3.9pF 0.25pF 50V     AVX Corporation   

                        Supplier PN  
0                GRM1555C1H101JA01D  
1                 CC0402JRNPO9BN101  
2  Murata Electronics North America  
3                    04025A6R8CAT2A  
4                  C0402C689C5GACTU  
5                    04025A3R9CAT2A
```

**How can I use Python Pandas to deal with it? Thanks.**

Comment: Do not include your data/expected output as images. Do include them as text.

Comment: I don't know how to put excel data as text here

Comment: @QuangHoang Yes, here I just copy the excel data and paste it

Comment: My apology, copy in Excel, paste into notepad, copy from there and paste here :D.

Comment: A better way is to do, with python: `print(pd.read_excel('path_to_file.xlsx'))`, then copy/paste from console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is very similar to `pd.wide_to_long` with a tweak. So you can try this code:

```
# sample data
# replaced with df=pd.read_excel(...)
df = pd.DataFrame({'P/N':[1,2,3],
                  'Description':['a','b','c'],
                  'Supplier':['x','y','z'],
                  'Supplier PN':['xx','yy','zz'],
                  'Supplier.1':['X','Y',np.nan],
                  'Supplier PN.1':['XX','YY',np.nan]})

(df.melt(['P/N','Description'])
   .dropna()
   .assign(stub=lambda x: x.variable.str.extract('([^\.]*)\.?'),
           idx=lambda x: x.groupby('stub').cumcount()
           )
   .pivot_table(index=['P/N','Description','idx'], 
                columns='stub', 
                values='value',
                aggfunc='first')
   .reset_index()
   .drop('idx', axis=1)
)
```

Or this code with `wide_to_long`:

```
df.columns = np.where(df.columns.str.match('^Supp.*\D+$'),
                      df.columns + '.0',
                      df.columns)

(pd.wide_to_long(df, ['Supplier', 'Supplier PN'],
               ['P/N', 'Description'], 
                'num', sep='.')
   .dropna()
   .reset_index()
   .drop('num',axis=1)
)
```

Output:

```
stub  P/N Description Supplier Supplier PN
0       1           a        x          xx
1       1           a        X          XX
2       2           b        y          yy
3       2           b        Y          YY
4       3           c        z          zz
```